# Perceptive MailChimp API - Problem creating new campaign

Tags: api, mailchimp

I am using the [PerceptiveMCAPI C# Wrapper](http://perceptivemcapi.codeplex.com/) for the MailChimp API to create a campaign but I'm receiving this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcStruct.Add(Object key, Object value) at PerceptiveMCAPI.Methods.campaignCreate.FormatCampaignOptions(campaignCreateOptions options) at PerceptiveMCAPI.Methods.campaignCreate.ExecuteXmlRpc()

This is my code

```
campaignCreateInput input = new campaignCreateInput();
        input.parms.type = PerceptiveMCAPI.EnumValues.campaign_type.auto;
        input.api_Validate = false;
        campaignCreateOptions options = new campaignCreateOptions();
        options.from_email = "info@domain.com";
        options.from_name = "Some Name";
        options.list_id = "xxxxxxxxx";
        options.subject = txtSubject.Text;
        options.authenticate = true;
        options.auto_footer = true;
        options.title = "SomeTitle";
        input.parms.options = options;
        Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        content.Add("html", FCKeditor1.Value);
        content.Add("text", "Lorem Ipsum");
        input.parms.content = content;

        campaignCreate cmd = new campaignCreate(input);
        return cmd.Execute();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: For those interested, a workaround for this problem has been discussed here http://perceptivemcapi.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=228303

Comment: @Dsyfa.. Did you find any solution for that... struggling from same problem.